# c++11 Aggregate Initialize two dimensional int vector from std::string dynamically?

Tags: c++11, vector, initialization, 2d, aggregate

I'm sorry if this has been asked before but i searched and couldn't find anything like the case i have, however i'm coming from C# so i'm still learning C++, i have a `std::string` that represents the int data for `vector<vector<int>>` like this:

> {
>   { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100 },
>
> { 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168, 169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216, 217, 218, 219, 220 }};

as you can see, the data is formatted same way when you aggregate initialize the `vector<vector<int>>`, how and what is the best way to load this data into `vector<vector<int>>` at runtime?

Please note, reformatting the data is not a problem since its coming from another application and i have the source code for that application and can change it to any format if it cannot be done with the supplied format.

Comment: There's no built-in functionality for this. You have to parse the string manually, e.g reading from it with `std::istringstream`.

Comment: @AntonSavin Thats what i wanted to know, thank you very much, i changed the formatting of the data , split each chunk, replace "," with WhiteSpace then load it in std::istringstream with std::istream_iterator into vector<int>